# Unable to connect to redis server deployed on Amazon ec2 on port 6379

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I have set up a redis server on AWS ec2 instance following https://medium.com/@andrewcbass/install-redis-v3-2-on-aws-ec2-instance-93259d40a3ce

I am running a python script on another ec2 instance

```
import redis

try:
    conn = redis.Redis(host=<private ip address>,port=6379, db=1)
    user = {"Name":"Pradeep", "Company":"SCTL", "Address":"Mumbai", "Location":"RCP"}
    conn.hmset("pythonDict", user)
    conn.hgetall("pythonDict")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

In the security groups of the redis server, i have allowed inbound traffic on port 6379

While running the above script, i am getting following error:

```
Error 111 connecting to 172.31.22.71:6379. Connection refused.
```

I have already tried changing the bind value in conf file, as suggested by a few answers to similar questions on stack overflow, but it didn't work

Comment: Modify your security groups temporarily to allow all outbound traffic from the client and all inbound traffic to the Redis server. Can you connect?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your other instance is within the same subnet as the Redis instance, my suggestion would be to review a couple of things:

1. Make sure among your security group inbound rules, you have your Redis port set up for the subnet, like:

   ```
   6379 (REDIS)    172.31.16.0/20
   ```
2. From within your `Redis` configuration (e.g. `/etc/redis/redis.conf`), in case this hasn't been done, either bind the server to the private IP (`bind 172.31.22.71`) or simply comment out any existing localhost binding, then restart `Redis`.